# Setting the state of a React Component from 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

I have two input fields type=file, in a react component. I have to load a json file in each of the input fields and then save the JSON file data in two different variables and update the state of the component. But when I try to do that, both of the file's data get saved in the same variable of state.

Here is the Component

```
export class comp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            uploadFile1:null,
            uploadFile2:null
        }
        this.readFile1 = this.readFile1.bind(this);
        this.readFile2 = this.readFile2.bind(this);
       
    }
    readFile1(e) {
        var file = document.querySelector("#file");
        if ( /\.(json)$/i.test(file.files[0].name) === false )
        { 
            alert("Not valid JSON file!"); 
        }
        else{
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
            fileReader.onload = e => {
                console.log(e.target.result);
                var data = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                
                this.setState({
                    uploadFile1: data
                })
            };
            
        }
    }
    readFile2(e) {
        var file = document.querySelector("#file2");
        if ( /\.(json)$/i.test(file.files[0].name) === false )
        { 
            alert("Not valid JSON file!"); 
        }
        else{
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
            fileReader.onload = e => {
                console.log(e.target.result);
                var data = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                
                this.setState({
                    uploadFile2: data
                })
            };
            
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                
              <input onChange={this.readFile1} type="file" id="file" className="inputfile"/>
              <label htmlFor="file">Browse for files</label>

                            
              <input onChange={this.readFile2} type="file" id="file2" className="inputfile"/>
              <label htmlFor="file">Browse for files</label>
                                
                            
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

There are two functions for reading files for both inputs. Although the ids for both the input fields are different but the data gets set in uploadFile1 for both the files.

Is there any problem with the ids of the input field? I cannot change the id of the input filed other than 'file'. If I don't that the above-mentioned problem arise.

Comment: ```<input onChange={this.readFile} type="file" id="file" className="inputfile"/>``` Just wondering where your this.readFile is coming from? It's not in the component as far as I can see.

Comment: Updated the code. It was by mistake over here. Now can you tell me the solution to the stated problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I strongly suspect the problem is that you're clicking on your labels, and both labels have `htmlFor="file"`, i.e. both labels point to the *first* file input.

In addition, your `onChange` method names are wrong. I guess that's part of inputting the question, but there could be an issue there, it's hard to tell given the code available.

In general, you shouldn't need to use the file ids or `querySelector` in your `onChange` methods to get the input values. Instead, you can use `e.target` to get the changed input directly. Using that you could reduce your code down to a single `readFile` method that can handle either input, which might make this easier to manage. Something like this:

```js
onFileChanged(changeEvt) {
    const file = changeEvt.target;
    const fileId = file.id;

    if (/\.(json)$/i.test(file.files[0].name) === false) {
        alert("Not valid JSON file!");
    } else {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsText(file.files[0], "UTF-8");

        fileReader.onload = () => {
            console.log(fileReader.result);
            const data = JSON.parse(fileReader.result);

            this.setState({
                ['upload-' + fileId]: data
            })
        };
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <input onChange={this.onFileChanged} type="file" id="file1" className="inputfile"/>
            <label htmlFor="file1">Browse for files</label>

            <input onChange={this.onFileChanged} type="file" id="file2" className="inputfile"/>
            <label htmlFor="file2">Browse for files</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I haven't properly tested that, but you get the idea. Note that I'm using a [computed property name](http://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript) in the `setState`, so you'll need to be in an environment (i.e. modern browser) where that's supported.

Comment: Can you show me an example code for doing the same thing with e.target instead of onChange function, please?

Comment: @AyeshaYounis Great! Once an answer solves your problem, you should accept it (click the ✓) so that everybody knows this question is resolved